# C# WinForms Expression Builder Linq

Tags: c#, linq, expression, builder

I am looking for a visual Linq expression builder for a WinForms application.  There is a project on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90589/Visual-Expression-Builder-for-Dynamic-Linq) that is exactly what I need, except it is WPF.

Does anyone know of open-source or commercial software that would accommodate me?

Basically I want to have a user control that I can bind to a type (class), and provide intuitive controls for user to select FIELD, FILTER TYPE (i.e. >=, like, =, etc) and a VALUE, and then be able to parse that information to run Linq against an IQueryable.

Comment: you can [use wpf in winform](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms)

Comment: That project on codeproject is pretty much garbage and I would rewrite it anyway, regardless of whether or not you back port it to winforms.

Answer (score 1):

UI technology doesn't change the behavior of expression trees.

Either port the WPF controls to WinForms, or just host the WPF controls inside your WinForms window via the [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) object.

Comment: Any advice for how to port that WPF control to winforms?

Comment: First, you should ask yourself whether there are real business reasons for porting the UI backwards to Windows Forms, considering WPF is WinForms' successor. If there are real business reasons, this MSDN article should get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750559.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[The article you referenced](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90589/Visual-Expression-Builder-for-Dynamic-Linq) in the question actually [links to a WinForms control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2007/08/29/implementing-dynamic-searching-using-linq.aspx) put together by the VB Team.

It looks like it might fit the bill. It's written in VB, but you should still be able to reference it from a C# project after you compile it.